# GTX 1070 Hashrate dropped from 30.8 to 28.3. Settings not changed

Tags: mining, mining-pools, windows, claymore, nvidia

I was running at an overclock of +600 on the memory clock and was getting about 30.8 for my hashrate. I tried overclocking to +700 but it didn't seem stable as I got some minor artifacting after about 10 minutes. I then reverted back to my old OC but my hashrate had gone down. This was about 9 hours ago now. What do I do?